# How can I combine multiple lines of text into one line in Python with a delimiter to separate them?

Tags: python, text

I have the following in a text file:

```
line1
text1
text2
text3
line2
something1
something2
```

I want to create another text file that looks like this:

```
line1|text1|text2|text3
line2|something1|something2
```

Whenever a line in the text file says "line" I want to add each line below it to that line with a '|' delimiter.  Can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your file is not EXTREMELY big

```
data=open("file").readlines()
for n,line in enumerate(data):
    if line.startswith("line"):
       data[n] = "\n"+line.rstrip()
    else:
       data[n]=line.rstrip()
print '|'.join(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner which uses `line1, line2, ...` without actually reading the number from that line:

```
['|'.join(['line%d' % i] + x.strip('\n').split('\n')) for i, x in enumerate(re.split('line[0-9]+', l)) if x.strip('\n')]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def join_lines(lines, sent='line'):
    current = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(sent):
            yield current
            current = []

        current.append(line)
    yield current

# data = open('input.txt', 'rt')
data = """line1
text1
text2
text3
line2
something1
something2""".splitlines()

print ['|'.join(line) for line in join_lines(data) if line]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
current = None 
parts = [] 
with open('input', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('line'):
            current = [line.strip()]
            parts.append(current)
        elif current is not None:
            current.append(line.strip())

with open('output', 'w+b') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(('|'.join(part) for part in parts)))
```